# Access 2016 How to remove duplicate

Tags: ms-access

I am making a form like this. User can enter something and show the results. For this picture, it will show all the information
[image]

But when user choose to not showing the EN number, it should be something like picture 2
[image]

But what I can get only like picture 3 which they are showing the duplicate cases.

They are repeated since I can only know using one source to make it.
[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Two ideas come to mind, adding a Group By or Distinct to the query. (May make the form read-only).  Physically remove the duplicate entries, access has a wizard for finding duplicates, as for removing them, that's a bit more advanced.

Comment: Thank you Kris. I have already using Croup By in query as well as tried finding duplicates in wizard. Since I should include all the information, therefore it will not count as a duplication because I am have different content in other columns(EN8 and EN10). So I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: How about using Sum or Count on fields 01 through 31?

Comment: Because I am using a crosstab. They are now showing by Count.

Comment: So you're saying that if someone leaves EN8 and EN10 blank that someone it not interesting in the date narrowed down by EN8 and EN10. Correct?

Comment: Sorry I am not really understand. Let me explain more, if someone dun want to show EN8 and EN10 they can choose to tick the check box above then the result will be the second picture (no duplicate in row). Otherwise it will show all the results. (Why I can conduct the second picture is because I am using another source query.)

Comment: The second and third images show the EN8 and EN10 columns are hidden. The data is still there and the records are still unique because of the EN10 value. Why do you need to bother hiding columns? GROUP BY and DISTINCT would definitely make the dataset non-editable.

Comment: So the form is based on a CROSSTAB query? Use VBA code to set the form RecordSource with a CROSSTAB that does not include the EN8 and EN10 fields as RowHeaders.

Comment: What I really want to do is, it is able to let someone input any related text in the text boxes and search for it. Since this is a very big database, therefore EN8 and EN10 is provided to choose if they want to consider it. If either one of it is selected, the filter will consider it as one of the constrains. To hide the column, it is meaning that the filter should not include that column. But I am actually fail just like the third images.

Comment: Yes, it is based on a crosstab query.

Comment: Thank you June. I think I get what I want by using VBA to set the RecordSource.